# Check if all values match a condition (x, y and z all should be 1)

Tags: python, tkinter

This might be kind of a stupid question, and I might be simply overlooking an obvious solution.

I want to check if variables X, Y, and Z are “1”, and if any of them are anything else I do not want to continue.

In the program I'm currently writing, I'm using Python3 & Tkinter. Nothing else.

Comment: I suggest you go through a beginner Python tutorial that covers conditions and variables. This is extremely basic.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

"1" i interpret as a string, so something like

```
if x == "1" and y == "1" and z == "1"
```

where z y and z are all the same type, str
or

```
if x == 1 and y == 1 and z == 1:
```

where x y and z are all the same type, int
tkinter should not matter, as python if statements & operators dont change within modules.
Be careful not to do what i originally did,

```
>>> if x and y and z == 1:
    print("sadf")

    
sadf
>>> y = 2\
>>> if x and y and z == 1:
    print("sadfasdf")

    
sadfasdf
>>> if x == 1 and y == 1 and z == 1:
    print("sdfasdf")

    
>>>
```

you can see that the first 2 do not give you the correct output, but the last does.

Comment: have you actually tried this? it does not do what OP asked

Comment: I did not realize you can use "and" within "if". That's the solution I was looking for. 
Tested it in my code, and it works exactly like I wanted it to. Thanks a lot.

Comment: chances are OP used the previous version which introduces a subtle bug that will be hard to understand for a beginner

Comment: hopefully he will come back...

Comment: Shorter version: `if x == y == z == "1":`.